# Where is the location of test plan tfsserver databases?

Tags: tfs, report

I know that tfsserver has built-in report server. But I want to get a custom report from test case steps. So I need to query some database that belongs to tfsserver. I need the name of this database and if it is possible the structure of it.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft doesn't support interacting directly with the operational databases.  If you want to get data out of TFS the supported ways are either the warehouse database (Tfs_Warehouse) - but I don't believe that includes test steps; the TFS Cube (Tfs_Analysis) - also doesn't include test steps; or the API - which should allow you to retrieve test steps.

So my advice is to retrieve the data from the API.  Or alternatively create a custom warehouse adapter that pushes this data over to the warehouse database.